# modules make: *** /lib/modules/3.7-trunk-amd64/build: No such file or directory

Tags: kernel, make, kali-linux

I need to install Kali Linux updates without Internet access on my laptop.

I think I need to do this because I'm trying to install the WiFi driver but I get an error when I try to make:

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS COMPILTE= -C /lib/modules/3.7-trunk-amd64/build M=/root/Desktop/rtl8723A_WiFi_linux_v4.1.3_6044.20121224 
modules make: *** /lib/modules/3.7-trunk-amd64/build: No such file or directory. Stop. 
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Trying to install the Realtek rtl8723au wireless driver WiFi driver:

- github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au (from https://askubuntu.com/questions/318608/…)

It's for the Yoga13, I can `cd /root/blah/driver`, but when I `make` it just spits out the aforementioned error message, that was the entire error message.

When using `dpkg -l | grep linux-` command, it yields this:

```
ii  firmware-linux-free         3.2               all       Binary firmware for various drivers in the Linux kernel
ii  firmware-linux-nonfree      0.37             all        Binary firmware for various drivers in the Linux kernel
ii  kali-linux-full             1.35             amd64      Penetration testing and security auditing distribution, full system
ii  kali-linux-sdr              1.35             amd64      Penetration testing and security auditing distribution, SDR tools
ii  linux-base                  3.5              all        Linux image base package
ii  linux-image-3.7-trunk-amd64 3.7.2-0+kali8    amd64      Linux 3.7 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-amd64           3.7+46+kali1     amd64      Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64        3.7.2-0+kali8    amd64      Linux support headers for userspace development
```

The OS is a fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

`/lib/modules/3.7-trunk-amd64/build` is a symbolic link to `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.7-trunk-amd64` which is provided by the `linux-headers` package on your distribution. Just install `linux-headers-amd64` in your system and you should be fine.